# VBA Weekday and Workday to replace Saturday and Sunday with next Monday

Tags: excel, weekday, vba

Quick question: I have a small vba script that fills a range of cells with dates based on a number of conditions.  I want to take this range of dates and replace any that fall on the weekend with the next Monday.  I'm trying to use `Weekday` and `Workday` to do this (please assume all variables are properly defined):

```
i = 6
For i = 6 to LastRow
    If Weekday(Cells(i, "I"), vbMonday) > 5 Then
        Cells(i, "I") = Application.WorksheetFunction.Workday(Cells(i, "I"), 1, 1)
    End If
Next i
```

As far as I can tell, `Weekday` is designed to accept a date, not a cell reference.  I'm not sure how to pass dates to it in a for loop.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Please add your input data example and the expected output too

Comment: If the cell you're referencing holds a date, just use `Weekday(Cells(i, "I").value, vbMonday)` - Same goes for the `WorksheetFunction.Workday()`. Also it's better to not do `Cells(i, "I") = `, but `Cells(i, "I").value = ` - in other words, explicitly assign the result to value.

Comment: One thing your missing is that there are two optional arguments. You should add , , before vbMonday.

Comment: Thank you guys very much.  Figured out what it was - some cells in that range contained text, which Weekday couldn't handle.  Simple issue I just missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by incrementing any Saturday by +2 or Sunday by +1. Because Saturday = 6 and Sunday = 7 if you use the `vbMonday` argument to the `Weekday` function) then this will work:

```
7 - lngDayIndex + 1
```

Where `lngDayIndex` is the return of the `Weekday` function.

Code example:

```
Sub ConvertToNextMonday()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lngLastRow As Long, lngCounter As Long, lngDayIndex As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2") '<-- change to your sheet
    lngLastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row '<-- change to your column

    For lngCounter = 1 To lngLastRow
        lngDayIndex = Application.WorksheetFunction.Weekday(ws.Cells(lngCounter, "I").Value, vbMonday)
        If lngDayIndex = 6 Or lngDayIndex = 7 Then
            ws.Cells(lngCounter, "I") = ws.Cells(lngCounter, "I") + (7 - lngDayIndex + 1)
        End If
    Next lngCounter

End Sub
```

According to the [Office support webpage](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Weekday-Function-05d360d7-2c3f-4691-9448-c96ea0351940), the `Weekday` function `date` argument can be:

> ...Variant, numeric expression, string expression, or any combination of these that can represent a date. If date contains Null, Null is returned.

So you can use:

```
Weekday(Now())
```

And also, e.g:

```
WeekDay("2017-10-25", vbMonday)
```

You just need to make sure any text values actually will properly convert to a date, given your regional settings.